# Params not being passed to method in Rails 3.0.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have another very puzzling question that has cropped up after my upgrade from Rails 2.3.4 to Rails 3.0.3.

I am calling a 'show' controller method with the following URL:

/verse/10

and I see this in the terminal

> Started GET "/verse/10" for 127.0.0.1
>   at 2011-01-27 16:17:58 -0800
>
> Processing by VersesController#show
>   as HTML
>   *** Searching for verse with ID:
>
> Rendered verses/show.html.erb within
>   layouts/application (76.6ms)
>
> Completed 200 OK in 1006ms (Views:
>   125.4ms | ActiveRecord: 9.8ms)

The verse show method is very simple:

```
  def show
    logger.debug("*** Searching for verse with ID: #{params[:id]}")
    @vs = Verse.find(params[:id])
  end
```

The route is defined as follows:

```
match '/verse/:id', :to => 'verses#show', :as => 'verse'
```

The problem: the parameter, ID, which in this case is '10', is not being passed in to the controller method and so a 404 is being thrown because params[:id] is nil.

The output from "rake routes | grep verse" is as follows:

> verse  /verse/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"verses", :action=>"show"}

I've spent ages on this but feel as though I'm missing something very obvious.

---

Here is the full rake routes output:

```
                   login        /login(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
                  logout        /logout(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
                register        /register(.:format)                               {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
                  signup        /signup(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
                activate        /activate/:activation_code(.:format)              {:activation_code=>nil, :controller=>"users", :action=>"activate"}
         forgot_password        /forgot_password(.:format)                        {:controller=>"passwords", :action=>"new"}
         change_password        /change_password/:reset_code(.:format)            {:controller=>"passwords", :action=>"reset"}
        open_id_complete GET    /opensession(.:format)                            {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}
          open_id_create GET    /opencreate(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                         POST   /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
               passwords GET    /passwords(.:format)                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"passwords"}
                         POST   /passwords(.:format)                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"passwords"}
            new_password GET    /passwords/new(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"passwords"}
           edit_password GET    /passwords/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"passwords"}
                password GET    /passwords/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"passwords"}
                         PUT    /passwords/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"passwords"}
                         DELETE /passwords/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"passwords"}
                 session POST   /session(.:format)                                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
             new_session GET    /session/new(.:format)                            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
            edit_session GET    /session/edit(.:format)                           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"sessions"}
                         GET    /session(.:format)                                {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sessions"}
                         PUT    /session(.:format)                                {:action=>"update", :controller=>"sessions"}
                         DELETE /session(.:format)                                {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
                  quests GET    /quests(.:format)                                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"quests"}
                         POST   /quests(.:format)                                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"quests"}
               new_quest GET    /quests/new(.:format)                             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"quests"}
              edit_quest GET    /quests/:id/edit(.:format)                        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"quests"}
                   quest GET    /quests/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"quests"}
                         PUT    /quests/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"quests"}
                         DELETE /quests/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"quests"}
                   index        /home(.:format)                                   {:controller=>"verses", :action=>"index"}
            starter_pack        /starter_pack(.:format)                           {:controller=>"verses", :action=>"starter_pack"}
                   *verse        /verse/:id(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"verses", :action=>"show"}*
               tag_cloud        /tag_cloud(.:format)                              {:controller=>"verses", :action=>"tag_cloud"}
          show_user_info        /show_user_info(.:format)                         {:controller=>"admin", :action=>"show_user_info"}
               show_tags        /show_tags(.:format)                              {:controller=>"admin", :action=>"show_tags"}
                 contact        /contact(.:format)                                {:controller=>"info", :action=>"contact"}
                     faq        /faq(.:format)                                    {:controller=>"info", :action=>"faq"}
                tutorial        /tutorial(.:format)                               {:controller=>"info", :action=>"tutorial"}
               volunteer        /volunteer(.:format)                              {:controller=>"info", :action=>"volunteer"}
             leaderboard        /leaderboard(.:format)                            {:controller=>"info", :action=>"leaderboard"}
              stateboard        /stateboard(.:format)                             {:controller=>"info", :action=>"stateboard"}
            countryboard        /countryboard(.:format)                           {:controller=>"info", :action=>"countryboard"}
           referralboard        /referralboard(.:format)                          {:controller=>"info", :action=>"referralboard"}
                    news        /news(.:format)                                   {:controller=>"info", :action=>"news"}
          update_profile        /update_profile(.:format)                         {:controller=>"profile", :action=>"update_profile"}
               referrals        /referrals/:id(.:format)                          {:controller=>"profile", :action=>"referrals"}
             unsubscribe        /unsubscribe/*email(.:format)                     {:controller=>"profile", :action=>"unsubscribe"}
                edit_tag        /edit_tag/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"tag", :action=>"edit_tag"}
                  tweets        /tweets(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"tweets", :action=>"index"}
           load_progress        /load_progress/:user(.:format)                    {:controller=>"chart", :action=>"load_progress"}
                    root        /(.:format)                                       {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
                    home        /home(.:format)                                   {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
                                /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)
```

Comment: Check the output of `rake routes` to make sure that's the actual route being matched. Also what is the result of `params.inspect`?

Comment: It may be a routing priority issue... can you post your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: I've added the output from 'rake routes' above. Params.inspect is an empty array: Params.inspect: {}

Comment: Any chance you're using the `open_id_authentication` plugin? There was a similar empty-params-hash problem recently and the problem was solved by removing this incompatible plugin. Another option would be removing everything under `vendor/plugins`, seeing if this route works, and then adding them back in one at a time.

Comment: Andy: whad dmarkow asked was the 'rake routes' output, to check there's no other route being matched first. The grep'ed output won't do - please post the full output.

Comment: Ok - I've posted the full rake routes output. Just for my own edification (i.e. not to be difficult) is there a way that the correct controller and method could process the call if a different route were matched first? (Also, there is a * next to the route that it should be matching. That's not in the actual route output ... I added it to show which route should be matched)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `open_id_authentication` plugin installed, that is likely interfering with your routes.